# HTTPS Redirect not working for images loaded within page

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, web-config

I know, another HTTPS redirect not working question. I have been at this for a while an cannot figure it out.

I have the following redirect rule in my web.config to redirect **ALL** HTTP traffic to HTTPS

```
  <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
  </rule>
```

This work great, no matter what URL I go to on HTTP, it redirects to HTTPS. Everything except images that are loaded from the within the page itself. Checkout the image below:

[image]

I have mixed content errors because all the images loaded **from my site**, are loading as HTTP. If I right click one of those images, and open in a new tab, the image opens as HTTPS. If I edit the image URL to say HTTP and hit return, it redirects to HTTPS and the image is loaded over HTTPS. But for some reason when the image is loaded via the page, it is managing to load over HTTP??!

Can anyone offer any advice on what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns browsers don't care what the end connection of a redirect chain is for content within a site on HTTPS. If the original connection of a file is HTTP then it will flag it as insecure and throw the mixed content warning, even if it actually terminates on HTTPS.

Until I can fix all the instances of HTTP, as a temp fix I have implemented the header

```
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

This causes the browser to upgrade HTTP links within the site to HTTPS, which has solved my mixed content warning.